# "Have in view" - origin

Tags: phrases

The phrase "have in view" also exists in two other languages that I know, in Russian and in Armenian: иметь в виду, ի նկատի ունենալ. This means it could have a common origin, perhaps Latin. My knowledge of Latin is very limited; I tried to find an equivalent phrase in Latin dictionaries but perhaps I didn't search under correct terms, so I didn't find what I needed. Can you help me find the origin of this phrase? Also, can you tell me if there are other languages too that have this same phrase?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't really think this idiom has any common etymology. For example, an equivalent Thai verb "จำ ไว้" `[tɕam wáj]` literally means "remember + hold".

Comment: IMHO there is no idiom in English like the one in Russian or Armenian.  There is "in sight" as in "no end in sight" in English (and German) and similarly "vista" in Romance languages but "vid" or "nkati" is not used in the equivalent expression in Russian or Armenian.

Comment: I would even question whether the Russian and Armenian one actually mean the same thing literally or figuratively.

Comment: I waded in assuming they both meant the same as the Greek equivalent. You tell me: what _do_ they mean in Russian and Armenian?

Comment: A. M. Bittlingmayer, "have in view" does exist in English too, with the same meaning as the Russian and Armenian equivalents. Maybe it's considered an archaism today; however, you can find many examples of its use in literature. Yes, the Armenian and Russian idioms mean the same thing.

Comment: Please see the examples here: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22have+in+view%22

Comment: Also here: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22has+in+view%22

Comment: "Have in view" as explained in Webster's 1913 Dictionary: http://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/To+have+in+view

Answer (score 2):

Modern Greek has "have under view = to be aware of", έχω υπ' όψιν and "take under view = to consider", λαμβάνω υπ' όψιν; the morphology is Ancient. The phrase is classic [Puristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katharevousa), but it appears to be mediaeval in origin, rather than calqued French or German (as was typical of such Puristic shibboleths).

The 11th century historian [Michael Attaliates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Attaleiates) used the variant "to bring down to view", μὴ κατ’ ὄψιν αὑτὸν ἀγαγών; [this 1875 commentary](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=9fNlAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA134&dq=%22%CF%85%CF%80%27%20%CE%BF%CF%88%CE%B9%CE%BD%22&hl=el&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-3cmp0qXcAhULnpQKHbTkCH0Q6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=%22%CF%85%CF%80'%20%CE%BF%CF%88%CE%B9%CE%BD%22&f=false) mentions "bringing under/down to view", ἄγω κατ’/ὑπ’ ὄψιν, as an idiom already in use in 4th century AD Church Fathers; e.g. [Gregory of Nyssa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_of_Nyssa), [Contra Eunomium I.130](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=Cc4TgIdERnYC&pg=PA66&dq=%22%CF%85%CF%80%27%20%CE%BF%CF%88%CE%B9%CE%BD%22&hl=el&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMn8W_06XcAhVMjJQKHYC3AP04PBDoAQgnMAA#v=onepage&q=%22%CF%85%CF%80'%20%CE%BF%CF%88%CE%B9%CE%BD%22&f=false): πῶς ἄν τις ὑπ’ ὄψιν ἀγάγοι τὸν καινὸν ἐκεῖνον ἀγῶνα, "how could anyone bring under view that new struggle" and the [New Advent translation](http://www.newadvent.org/fathers/290101.htm) treats it fairly literally:

> None could describe his contempt of danger, so as to **bring before the reader's eyes this new combat**, which one might justly say was waged not between man and man, but between a Christian's firmness and courage on the one side, and a bloodstained power on the other.

You can see the metaphor "bring before one's eyes" transforming into the fixed expression "to take before one's eyes = to consider" and "to have before one's eyes = to be aware of".

You can also see a Mediaeval Greek idiom, used by eminent theologians, being studiously copied by translators into other languages professing Eastern Christianity (like, say, Armenian and Russian), and becoming part of their written and formal language.

This isn't proof; but if there's no comparable idiom nearby in Europe, I'd think it's plausible. And given mediaeval history, Greek is much more plausible than Latin for explaining a fixed phrase in Armenian and Russian.

Comment: "if there's no comparable idiom nearby in Europe": I say that, because "have in view" is not an English idiom at all, though I suspect @Graser thinks it is. (The English idiom is "have in mind".)

Comment: "Have in view" does exist in English too, with the same meaning as the Russian and Armenian equivalents. Maybe it's considered an archaism today; however, you can find many examples of its use in literature.

Comment: In case of the Armenian idiom, it's not attested in medieval Armenian texts and in Classical Armenian translations of Greek texts. That's why I don't think its origin is Greek. We find it in the Armenian texts of the last several centuries when Armenian was influenced by other languages than Greek, mostly Latin and French, for example.

Comment: English: huh, so it is. I like to think I'm somewhat well-read, but I honestly had never come across it before. Ok, then things open up.